# Show that $S = \{\bigcup_{n\in K}(n, n+1]: K \subset Z\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on R

Tags: measure-theory

> Show that $S = \{\bigcup_{n\in K}(n, n+1]: K \subset Z\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on R

Denoting $E_n = (n, n+1]$, first I check that $\bigcup_{n\in K}E_n \in S$. From elementary set theory, the union of sets in $S$ is finite so the union is contained in $S$. To show that the complement $S/E_n \in S$, note that the complement of $E_n \in S$ is $\bigcup_{n\in K: ~n ~\neq k}E_n$, which was previously shown to be in $S$, thus $S/E_n \in S$ for all $E_n$.

However, how is $\emptyset\in S$? It doesn't seem obvious from the definition of $S$ how $\emptyset$ is even in $S$ in the first place.

Comment: The empty union (i.e. $K = \emptyset$) is by definition the empty set.